# React native expo async storage checkbox

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

## Im trying to save a checkbox to asyncstorage and reading it but it doesn't work

#### This is the Checkbox component it gets the async storage @key through props

#### I have multiple checkboxes because of that i made a component i dont know if that is the proplem

Checkbox.tsx:

```
export default function Checkbox({ storeId }: CheckboxProps) {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#fd4e4e')

  function changeSelect() {
    setIsSelected(!isSelected)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      await readData(storeId)
      await storeData(isSelected, storeId)
    }

    data()
  }, [isSelected])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = async () => {
      await readData(storeId)
      await storeData(isSelected, storeId)
    }

    data()
  }, [])

  const storeData = async (value: any, storeId: string) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(storeId, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
    }
  };

  const readData = async (storeId: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storeId)
      if (value !== null) {
        if (value === 'true') {
          if (isSelected) {
            setIsSelected(true)
          }
        }
        if (value === 'false') {
          if (!isSelected) {
            setIsSelected(false)
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable
        onPress={changeSelect}
        style={[styles.checkboxBase, { borderColor: color }, isSelected && { backgroundColor: color }]}
      >
        {isSelected && <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-sharp" size={40} color="white" style={styles.icon} />}
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `readData` method, you had written a condition that will never be satisfied,

```js
const readData = async (storeId: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storeId)
      if (value !== null) {
        if (value === 'true') {
          if (isSelected) { // remove this check. 
            setIsSelected(true)
          }
        }
        if (value === 'false') {
          if (!isSelected) { // not required 
            setIsSelected(false)
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
```

change your component to,

```js
function Checkbox({ storeId }) {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#fd4e4e') // you are not using this setColor anywhere.

  const changeSelect = () => {
    storeData(!isSelected, storeId);
    setIsSelected(value => !value) // change value based on the previous value
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    readData(storeId)
  }, []);

  const storeData = async (value: any, storeId: string) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(storeId, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) { }
  };

  const readData = async (storeId: string) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(storeId)
      if (value != null) {
        setIsSelected(JSON.parse(value)); // set the isSelected to the value from storage
      }
    } catch (e) { }
  }

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={changeSelect}
      style={[{
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderWidth: 2,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        margin: 5
      }, { borderColor: color }, isSelected && { backgroundColor: color }]}
    >
      {isSelected && <Text>✔️</Text>}
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

The other mistake in the code : You have the `isSelected` as `false` by default and you were also calling the `storeData` method on mount. Which eventually sets your `isSelected` to false always.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: When i reload the app the values are false again

Comment: @robinnlmn try the updated code

Comment: @robinnlmn Kindly accept the answer if found useful :)